# What does the -b option do in SFTP

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, sftp

I'm looking at some old shell scripts and there is a line that I don't quite understand:

```
~]$ sftp -b /dev/fd/3 dropuser@targetftpserver.company.com
```

I can see from the man file that -b is for batch, and that the argument is supposed to be a batchfile.

In this case, it looks like the batch file is supposed to be on a /dev/fd/3 - a floppy drive ?  I can't seem to get to it.

Any ideas what this is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"/dev/fd*"` files are special devices. These aren't really taking up that much space on your system. They allow a process to access file descriptors by number; `0,1,2` are standard `input`, `standard output` and `standard error`, and other open files start with `3`

In your case `sftp` using `-b` to read command from `/dev/fd/3`

Example:

```
[root@04 fd]# exec 3< /etc/resolv.conf
[root@04 fd]# cat /dev/fd/3
search example.com 

nameserver 10.10.10.10
nameserver 20.20.20.20
```

You can read data using `read` command

```
[root@04 fd]# read -u 3 a b
[root@04 fd]# echo $a $b
nameserver 10.10.10.10
```

output of `/dev/fd` directoy

```
[root@04 fd]# ls -l /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb 20 14:34 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb 20 14:34 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb 20 14:34 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Feb 20 14:34 3 -> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Notes: In your case that input file could be different

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/fd` isn't actually the floppy drive -- "fd" stands for "file descriptor." Try `man fd` in a terminal.

This page gives an overview of what's going on: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwinos-users/2004/Apr/msg00042.html. Basically, the first file SFTP writes to (perhaps the file it downloads?) is being passed back into itself as the batch file.

Without seeing the whole script or knowing SFTP's internals, I can't tell exactly what's going on. I'd guess that there's a list of files on the server the script connects to, and /dev/fd/3 is used to get SFTP to download the list and then download the files without reconnecting.